# Trying to access JSON data throws error on first click, but works on second click

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm building a simple app that accesses an API and renders out information.  It's activated by an event listener in a button, which takes the value of the html input field and plugs it into my `apiCall` function.  My code then processes the api response and assigns the desired data to a variable inside of an object, which is then console.log'ged out.

Here's my problem: when I click the button the first time, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'average_price')
    at Object.getAveragePrice (index.js:17)
    at render (index.js:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:33)
```

Then I click the button for the second time, and I get the correct data in my console.  What am I doing wrong? Below is my javascript.

```
let jsonResponse = ""
let collectionName = ""
let inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
let buttonEl = document.getElementById("button-el")


function callApi(collectionName) {
    fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${collectionName}/stats`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => jsonResponse = response)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

const getJsonData = {
    getAveragePrice: function() {
        collectionData.averagePrice = jsonResponse.stats["average_price"]
    }
}

let collectionData = {
    averagePrice: ""
}

function render() {
    callApi(collectionName)
    getJsonData.getAveragePrice()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collectionData.averagePrice))
}

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    collectionName = inputEl.value
    render()
})
```

Comment: because you're calling an async function and then trying to access it's result before it's had a chance to complete. There are numerous SO posts about this

Answer (score 0):

I se a couple of issues on your code, the one that you are encountering is:

First, It's because the initial value of `jsonResponse` is a string and you are accessing it as an object.

```
let jsonResponse = ""
```

yet you're accessing it as:

```
jsonResponse.stats["average_price"]
```

Changing the default value to this will fix the error:

```
let jsonResponse = {
  stats: {
    average_price: 0
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, this will "not fix" your logic, because what you are expecting is that the `callApi` has finished calling before the `getJsonData.getAveragePrice()` will be triggered.

That is the second issue where you need to either use async/await or promise to fulfill this.

I added some comments on the code improvements:

```
function callApi(collectionName) {
    // return the promise
    return fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${collectionName}/stats`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => jsonResponse = response)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

// make this function async
async function render() {
    // add await on call API so it will finish the promise first
    await callApi(collectionName)
    getJsonData.getAveragePrice()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collectionData.averagePrice))
}

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    collectionName = inputEl.value
    await render()
})
```